# "The system couldn't find the path specified" batch file error

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I'm new to batch file scripting language and im trying to make a bat file that saves some data for me.butwhen i try to use the command:

```
    echo 500>"%~dp0save\%user%-%pass%\power.sav"
```

this error occurs: The system cannot find the path specified.
i need a solution quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the directory before writing to it:

```
md "%~dp0save\%user%-%pass%\ 2>nul
```